# Best way to ask a question about folk music recordings?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

This question was closed: [Where can I find Bartók's field recordings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/86303/9198)

I understand why; it is asking for resources. However, the transcription of folk music by both classical composers and other musicians seems like a really important subject. And finding ways to access original transcriptions or recordings would be really useful. (I’m not sure I’d know how to find them!)

How could this kind of question be asked and be on topic? Does it just need to be more “general”, asking about the quickest ways to find these kind of resources (besides just giving somebody a LMGTFY link...)?

Comment: What could work is asking an indirect question, and hoping that someone will link to what you're looking for in their answer. Like "how faithfully did Bartók transcribe his field recordings?" or "where in Bartók's music can you see a direct influence of his field recordings?" or "which folk styles did Bartók record?"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that type of question just isn't suitable for the way stack exchange works. Finding resources is something others sites, and search engines do very well, though, so I think instead of trying here, just go for the Google option for these.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, resources questions can work fine on SE sites. We allow them on Korean.SE with no problems.

A long time back there was a very influential post -  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ - which makes some good points, but perhaps not ones that can be extrapolated to every type of resource question on every site.

I can see that *some* types of resources questions could be tedious here (where can I find the tab to XYZ)… so one possible way to go would be to find a line between 'good' and 'bad' resources questions, and 'campaign' for a slight rule tweak!

Comment: I don't think we should just allow __all__ resource recommendations and tweak it later. In fact, it should be the opposite we should ask the hard questions now like the following: Why do they make sense here? What should we allow and why? What benefit does it bring to the site if are just redirecting people to another site?

Comment: @Dom Yep - precisely what I was referring to by "finding the line" (if, indeed, there is one).